# Determine if three (or more) given time ranges overlap in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have three data frames (`df1`, `df2`, and `df3`) with start and end dates that indicate when an event has occurred. I know how to determine if overlap occurs between `df1` and either `df2` or `df3` but I don't know how to determine when overlap occurs between all data frames. Ideally, if `df2` and `df3` are within the start and end dates of `df1` then this would be indicated by a new column `Overlap` with results `TRUE` when all three data frames overlap in time and `FALSE` when all three data frames do not overlap in time.

```
> df1$aa
    date_start  date_end    Site  Variable
1   2002-04-12  2002-04-21  aa    Temp1
2   2002-06-26  2002-07-05  aa    Temp1
3   2002-08-15  2002-08-20  aa    Temp1
4   2005-08-08  2005-08-19  aa    Temp1
```

```
> df2$bb
    date_start  date_end    Site  Variable
1   2002-04-13  2002-04-19  aa    Temp2
2   2002-08-11  2002-08-19  aa    Temp2
3   2005-06-09  2005-06-14  aa    Temp2
4   2005-08-10  2005-08-14  aa    Temp2
```

```
> df2$cc
    date_start  date_end    Site  Variable
1   2002-04-14  2002-04-19  aa    Temp3
2   2002-08-11  2002-08-19  aa    Temp3
3   2005-06-09  2005-06-14  aa    Temp3
4   2005-08-10  2005-08-14  aa    Temp3
```

This code determines if there is overlap between `df1` and `df2` **OR** `df3`.

```
df1$aa$Overlap <- df1$aa$date_start %in% unlist(Map(':', df2$aa$date_start, df2$aa$date_end))
```

Ideally, the above code would be able to incorporate overlap between `df1`, `df2` and `df3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the dataframe in a list. Generate a sequence of days for each dataframe and find the common dates which are present in all 3 of them using `intersect`. You can then add a new column `Overlap` in `df1` if the `common_days` is present in range of `df1`.

```
list_df <- list(df1, df2, df3)
common_days <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(list_df, function(x) 
                      unlist(Map(':', x$date_start, x$date_end))))

df1$Overlap <- mapply(function(x, y) any(x:y %in% common_days),
                      df1$date_start, df1$date_end)

df1

#  date_start   date_end Site Variable Overlap
#1 2002-04-12 2002-04-21   aa    Temp1    TRUE
#2 2002-06-26 2002-07-05   aa    Temp1   FALSE
#3 2002-08-15 2002-08-20   aa    Temp1    TRUE
#4 2005-08-08 2005-08-19   aa    Temp1    TRUE
```

Comment: So it's not really that I want to know when all three overlap in time, rather what I would like to know is IF a Temp1 event occurs, how often does a Temp2 AND Temp3 event co-occur with the Temp1 event (what I'm calling a triple whammy)?

Comment: could you please ask that as a new question?