# If event 1 occurs, how often does event 2 AND event 3 co-occur?

Tags: r, dataframe, date

I have a heating system with three thermostats. If my first thermostat gets too hot it ***may*** cause my second to get too hot (although therm 2 could get too hot from other sources), if my second gets too hot it ***may*** cause my third to get too hot. What I would like to know is...if my first thermostat gets too hot (recorded as an `Event` with a `date_start` and `date_end`) how often do events in my second AND third thermostat co-occur (what I'm calling a triple whammy event)?

I would define a triple whammy event as such...The `date_start` of `Temp2` ***AND*** `Temp3` would have to occur between the `date_start` and `date_end` of Temp1.

```
> df1$Therm1
    date_start  date_end    Event Site
1   2002-04-12  2002-04-21  1     Therm1
2   2002-06-26  2002-07-05  2     Therm1
3   2002-08-15  2002-08-20  3     Therm1
4   2005-08-08  2005-08-19  4     Therm1
```

```
> df2$Therm2
    date_start  date_end    Event Site
1   2002-04-13  2002-04-19  1     Therm2
2   2002-08-11  2002-08-19  2     Therm2
3   2005-06-09  2005-06-14  3     Therm2
4   2005-08-10  2005-08-14  4     Therm2
```

```
> df3$Therm3
    date_start  date_end    Event Site
1   2002-04-14  2002-04-19  1     Therm3
2   2002-08-11  2002-08-19  2     Therm3
3   2005-06-09  2005-06-14  3     Therm3
4   2005-08-10  2005-08-14  4     Therm3
```

In this example a triple whammy event occurs during the `1` and `4` `Event` of `df1$Therm1` because the `date_start` in `df2$Therm2` ***AND*** `df3$Therm3` occur between the `date_start` and `date_end` of Events in `df1$Therm1`.

Comment: @Ronak Shah here is the question from https://stackoverflow.com/q/62767960/12836787 posed in another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is using lubridate functions `interval` and `%within%`. They're pretty clearly named; `interval` creates a time period and `%within%` checks whether a supplied time point is within that interval.

Assuming that `df1...df3` are actual data frames and not lists of dataframes as they appear to be in the question, we firstly add an `interval` variable to `df1`, which is our reference interval. We also need to transform the `start` dates of `df2` and `df3` into `date` objects with `ymd`:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(interval = interval(
      start = start, end = end))

df2 <- df2 %>% 
    mutate(start = ymd(start))

df3 <- df3 %>%
    mutate(start = ymd(start))
```

Then it could be as simple as looking for `start` times from `df2` and `df3` that are within `df1$interval`:

```
df1$event[which(df2$start %within% df1$interval & df3$start %within% df1$interval)]
# [1] 1 4
```

This assumes that there is a constant number of events across each thermostat (i.e., consistent with your example data), but I don't think that's what you really want. I think a more robust approach would be to check whether a particular interval has `start` dates within it from both `df2` and `df3`, e.g.,

```
df1 %>% 
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(tripleWhammy =
        any(df2$start %within% interval) &
        any(df3$start %within% interval))

## A tibble: 4 x 6
## Rowwise: 
#  start     end       event site  interval                       #tripleWhammy
#  <chr>     <chr>     <dbl> <chr> <Interval>                     <lgl>       
#1 2002-04-… 2002-04-…     1 Ther… 2002-04-12 UTC--2002-04-21 UTC TRUE        
#2 2002-06-… 2002-07-…     2 Ther… 2002-06-26 UTC--2002-07-05 UTC FALSE       
#3 2002-08-… 2002-08-…     3 Ther… 2002-08-15 UTC--2002-08-20 UTC FALSE       
#4 2005-08-… 2005-08-…     4 Ther… 2005-08-08 UTC--2005-08-19 UTC TRUE
```

Data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
      start = c('2002-04-12', '2002-06-26', '2002-08-15', '2005-08-08'),
      end = c('2002-04-21', '2002-07-05', '2002-08-20', '2005-08-19'),
      event = c(1,2,3,4),
      site = 'Therm1')

df2 <- data.frame(
    start = c('2002-04-13', '2002-08-11', '2005-06-09', '2005-08-10'),
    end = c('2002-04-19', '2002-08-19', '2005-06-14', '2005-08-14'),
    event = c(1,2,3,4),
    site = 'Therm2')

df3 <- data.frame(
    start = c('2002-04-14', '2002-08-11', '2005-06-09', '2005-08-10'),
    end = c('2002-04-19', '2002-08-19', '2005-06-14', '2005-08-14'),
    event = c(1,2,3,4),
    site = 'Therm3')
```